# In Mapstruct, how to ignore null objects and fields

Tags: spring-boot, mapping, mapstruct, java-17, mapper

Dears,

I am using mapstruct in my project(version: 1.5.2.Final, compiler: IncrementalProcessingEnvironment from gradle-language-java-7.6.1.jar, environment: Java 17.0.8).

I am trying to ignore null values but it didn't work. could you help me, please?

[image]

Above the picture, packet is null and called packetToPacketDTO, but it is not null in packetToPacketDTO

Also on last picture, effectiveDate should be null but it passes null check.

[image]

[image]

I want to ignore null values.

My mapper:

```
@Mapper( nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE )
public interface PacketItemInstanceMapper{


    PacketItemInstanceMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( PacketItemInstanceMapper.class );
    PacketItemInstanceDTO toDTO(PacketItemInstance entity);
    List<PacketItemInstanceDTO> toDTO(List<PacketItemInstance> entities);
    default PacketItemInstanceDTO getFirstDTO(List<PacketItemInstance> entities){
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(entities)){
            return null;
        }
        return toDTO(entities.get(0));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Hibernate issue. The `nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` that you set is what you are looking for.

```
@Mapper( nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE )
```

However, as you can see inside the debugger, you are holding a Hibernate proxy  (`product = {Product$HibernateProxy$X2....}`). The getters will load the data behind it, which is **not** null. You can see this, by evaluating `product.getEffectiveDate()` in the debugger.

In your case, you may need to unproxy the `product`, or find another way to load it from the database. See for example [this article by Thorben Janssen](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-proxies/).